# Cycle Through a List in a List of Lists with Map and display them

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks

I need to cycle through a list in list of lists in data and retrieve the indexes in order to display them in my Reactjs project. I can't seem to find a way to do it correctly without it either bugging out if the index goes to far OR how to display more than one inside an   that will display them one by one on the screen.

Here is the data for code if it clears up anything:

```js
const recettes = [
  {
    id: 0,
    nom: "Quiche aux poireaux",
    tprep: "1h35",
    portions: 6,
    ingredients: [
      {
        nom: "Pâte brisée",
        qte: "1",
      },
      {
        nom: "Oeufs",
        qte: "6",
      },
      {
        nom: "Poireau emincé",
        qte: "240g",
      },
      {
        nom: "Fromage gruyère",
        qte: "125g",
      },
      {
        nom: "Crème 35%",
        qte: "500ml",
      },
    ],
    preparation:
      "Étaler la pâte dans un moule à tarte. Faire cuire le poireau dans le beurre 5 minutes ou jusqu'à ce qu'il soit tombé. Dans un bol, fouetter les œufs. Ajouter la crème, les trois quarts du poireau et le fromage. Poivrer. Verser dans la croûte. Répartir le reste du poireau. Cuire au four 1 h 15 ou jusqu'à ce que la quiche soit légèrement dorée et que le centre soit tout juste pris. Couper en pointes et servir.",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    nom: "Curry de pois chiches et chou-fleur",
    tprep: "20 minutes",
    portions: 2,
    ingredients: [
      {
        nom: "Coriandre moulue",
        qte: "10 ml",
      },
      {
        nom: "Garam masala",
        qte: "10 ml",
      },
      {
        nom: "Gingembre moulu",
        qte: "2,5 ml",
      },
      {
        nom: "Ail émincé",
        qte: "1/2 gousse",
      },
      {
        nom: "Harissa",
        qte: "1 ml",
      },
      {
        nom: "Têtes de chou-fleur",
        qte: "200g",
      },
      {
        nom: "Pois chiches rincés",
        qte: "400 ml",
      },
      {
        nom: "Oignon émincé",
        qte: "1",
      },
      {
        nom: "Huile d'olive",
        qte: "30 ml",
      },
      {
        nom: "Lait de coco",
        qte: "160 ml",
      },
    ],
    preparation:
      "Dans une poêle à feu moyen, attendrir l'oignon dans l'huile 5 minutes. Ajouter le mélange d'épices et l'ail et poursuivre la cuisson 2 minutes en remuant. Ajouter le mélange de chou-fleur, le lait de coco et l'eau. Porter à ébullition et laisser mijoter 10 minutes ou jusqu'à ce que le chou-fleur soit tendre. Ajouter de l'eau au besoin. Servir avec des quartiers de lime et des pains naans grillés, si désiré.",
  },
];
```

and here is the React code to display them:

```js
export default function Recette() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  if (counter < 0) {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="name-page">
        <br />

        <div className="topBlock">
          <div className="Recette-name">
            <div className="Section-button">
              <button
                onClick={() => setCounter(counter - 1)}
                className="buttons"
              >
                <div className="button-text">Precedant</div>
              </button>{" "}
              <button
                onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}
                className="buttons"
              >
                <div className="button-text">Suivant</div>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="text-section-name">
              <h2>{donnees[counter].nom}</h2>

              <h3>Temp de preparation: {donnees[counter].tprep} </h3>

              <h3>Portions: {donnees[counter].portions} </h3>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="Recette-image">
            <img className="quiche" src={quiche}></img>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div className="bottomBlock">
          <div className="Recette-ingredients">
            <h3 className="recette-title">Ingredients</h3>
            <li className="ingredient-list">
              <h4 className="recette-data-name">
                {donnees[counter].ingredients[0].nom}
              </h4>{" "}
              <h4 className="recette-data-qte">
                {donnees[counter].ingredients[0].qte}
              </h4>
            </li>
          </div>

          <div className="Recette-Preparation">
            <h3 className="preparation-title">Preparation</h3>
            <h4 className="preparation-textArea">{donnees[0].preparation}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I use a useState function to calculate the main Index of the list I want to access and display it correctly but I tried adding it to a   to see if more would show but only one displays itself.
I tried using the "map" object but I had no idea on how to correctly make it cycle through without overshooting the index of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could solve this is by creating a function which handles the **next/previous** functionality.

```js
function cycleCounter(delta) {
  // use the callback function to get the previous value.
  setCounter((prev) => {
    // get the new counter
    const newCounter = prev + delta;
    // check if its below 0 then return the length to go to the last
    if (newCounter < 0) return donnees.length;
    // check if its bigger than the length then return 0
    if (newCounter >= donnees.length) return 0;
    // if we're not on a edge simply return the new counter
    return newCounter;
  });
}
```

Now you can use this function for your buttons and pass the `delta` at which you want to cycle.

```js
<div className="Section-button">
  <button onClick={() => cycleCounter(-1)} className="buttons">
    <div className="button-text">Precedant</div>
  </button>{" "}
  <button onClick={() => cycleCounter(+1)} className="buttons">
    <div className="button-text">Suivant</div>
  </button>
</div>
```

To display all the ingredients of the current recipe you can use a `.map` like so

```js
<ul>
  {donnees[counter].ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
    <li className="ingredient-list">
      <h4 className="recette-data-name">{ingredient.nom}</h4>
      <h4 className="recette-data-qte">{ingredient.qte}</h4>
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: That seems like a good way of handling it but it needs to happen all at the same time because the current index counter i use display only the main indexes of the list and not the indexes of the indexes.

In other words, it just shows me the recipe's main info but I need either another function that displays ALL ingredients in the list of Ingredients shown above.

Comment: You can use a `.map` for that and return a element from the callback. @Sirmator I've updated my answer.

Comment: could you explain to me how I could use .map to display them all because I don't know the correct format on where to place it in my code for it to be effective.

I think I could use it by doing:

{donnees[counter].ingredients.map(nom)}

Comment: I recommend this article from the [react.dev website about rendering lists](https://react.dev/learn#rendering-lists) for more information.

Comment: I found a way to display them. 
it worked as I intended I'm having CSS issues but i think I should be ok

i'll try and show the code I used